# Error: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/ . while using Ubuntu in virtual box

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to use ubuntu:20.04 on oracle virtual box. I am a windows user.
I am unable to use pip or pip3 as it raises an error:
" Error:pip3 command not found" . When I tried using

> sudo easy_install pip3
> it showed
> " Error: easy_install command not found" .

When I tried using:

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

I again got an error:

> " Error: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate".

Then I run this command :

> sudo apt-get update

Then when I run the following command I got an error :

> sudo apt-get upgrade

> I got the following Error: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/ .

The output of my df -H command is:
[image: The image shoes the error]

Please help, I want to install pip on my virtual machine (ubuntu)

Comment: This is not related to programming, error on installing a package is more appropriate on Unix SE and AskUbuntu, both already have the dupe of this question

Answer (score 1):

You need to install python3 first, then you'll able to install python3-pip.

Follow these steps to install python3 http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

And set your python3.x to python3 then you'll able to install python3-pip